# Javascript/jQuery | Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input?

Tags: jquery

jQuery noob checking in here. What is wrong with my syntax? I get Unexpected End of Input in Chrome console.

```
 <script>
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
  if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
     || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

     var target = $(this.hash);
     target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
        if (target.length) {
          $('html,body').animate({
              scrollTop: target.offset().top
         }, 1000);
         return false;
        }
     }
 });
</script>
```

Comment: How do you know the problem is there to begin with?

Comment: Because it shows on line 21 of my site, which is </script>

Comment: Please paste all the relevant source

Comment: @Alexander, That's all the relevant source there is. Line 21 is </script> above it is a <title> and two tags specifying the html and head tag.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It means you've forgotten a closing `}, ), >`, or whatever is used in its syntax. Check all of your blocks and statements to see if you've left out any closing mark.

if you copy your code into [jsbeautifier.org](http://jsbeautifier.org/), click on "Beautify" and see if all of the indentations are correct.

Comment: jsbeautifier.org fixed it all =] Thank you.